# jwplayer does'nt work .getPlaylist is not a function

Tags: jwplayer6

I try to use jwplayer (6.2 version) on a website. It works well on my computer and some others but it doesn't work on all. I tried lot of things like install / reinstall / update Flash etc...
The error is still the same:
Uncaught TypeError: d(...).getPlaylist is not a function
    at l.model.j.setPlaylist (jwplayer.html5.js:153)
    at Object.method (jwplayer.html5.js:193)

HEre my sample code:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.videos').each(function(){ 
        var movie = $(this);
        jwplayer(movie.attr('id')).setup($.extend({}, jwplayerDefault, {
            file: movie.attr('data-url'),
            image: movie.attr('data-image'),
            width: '100%',
            height: 150
        }));
    });
});


    <div class="col-xs-12 logo video-box no-padding ">
  <div id="{{ oVideo.getId() }}" class="videos" data-image="{{ oVideo.getPicto() }}" data-url="{{ oVideo.getPath() }}" data-image="{{ oVideo.getPicto() }}">Loading the player...</div>  </div>
```

I have checked that any argument was existing (and it is).

Any help?

Comment: It was a bug on 6.2 version: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062437-getplaylistitem-index-undefined  You need to upgrade jwplayer 6 (but it's deprecated) or to use the new jwplayer 7 (I suggest it)

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll check it and see if it resolves everything (hope so :) )